# How to view passwords of key chain on iPad?

Tags: ipad, keychain

I'm using iCloud. I know that passwords for web sites which are saved in Keychain Access app can be viewed on iPad, but I want to see other passwords on that app.

For example, I saved the password of my Timemachine backup in my Keychain Access app. When my PC is broken and I want to recover it from a backup, I have to read that password from other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud keychain only does web login, and the mac keychain has added functionality in a local keychain. My workaround to this is to make up a fake website and add your password via your iPad using the fake domain. For example, add your password with username "Time_Machine" and website "time_machine_password.com". It's not perfect but it gets the job done.